# Where is the default cache location of Go test files?

Tags: go, testing, caching

From the Go testing [documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Testing_flags):

> When 'go test' runs in package list mode, 'go test' caches successful package test results to avoid unnecessary repeated running of tests.

This all works fine for me. However, I cannot find an official list of cache directories per platform in the documentation. I can take a guess that it might be stored in `$HOME/.cache/go-build` on Linux?

So far I have read the [source code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/go/internal/test/test.go), searched the documentation (as linked above), and read the output of `go help test` and `go help cache` but still can't see a definitive answer.

Comment: I think you're confused because the source code you linked to isn't the test command, it's tests for the `go` command.

Comment: @JimB Sorry, I completely linked to the wrong file - updated the link.

Comment: @icza Thanks - that does answer my question.